# Adding message beside product when adding to basket

Tags: angularjs

When I add an item to my basket I want to make it easy for the user to see that they have added that item to their basket when viewing the product catalog.  Currently when I add the item to the basket the message `added to basket` appears beside every product.  I want this to appear beside the product they just added.

How would I do this?

This is the code I've got so far which adds items to the basket:

```
$scope.addToBasket = function(item){
  $scope.basket.push(item);
  $scope.addedToBasket = 'added to basket';
}


<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div  ng-click="addToBasket(item)">
    {{item.name}} &nbsp; {{item.price}}   {{addedToBasket}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code

```
$scope.addToBasket = function (item) {
    $scope.basket.push(item);
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function (objItem) {
        objItem.addedToBasket = angular.equals(objItem, item) ? 'added to basket' : '';
    });
}

<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div  ng-click="addToBasket(item)">
    {{item.name}} &nbsp; {{item.price}}   {{item.addedToBasket}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

The property has to exist by item not by class:

```
$scope.addToBasket = function(item){
 $scope.basket.push(item);
 item.customMessage="Added to basket";
}

<div ng-repeat="item in items">
 <div  ng-click="addToBasket(item)">
  {{item.name}} &nbsp; {{item.price}}   {{item.customMessage}}
 </div>
</div>
```